# Gods and demons (Indra and Diti)

Tags: puranas

In matsya purana, [Indra killed many of Diti's children.](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/matsya_purana/vajranaga%20.html)

Why Indra killed many of Diti's children and why Indra death is calamity although lord Brahma don't mind and and agreed that Indra will killed by Vajranga's son?

> "When the thousand years were over, Vajranga returned. He was shocked to learn of the tortures that his wife had been subjected to by Indra. He began to meditate again. This time, he wished for a son who would kill Indra. Brahma appeared and granted Vajranga the desired boon."

Comment: You are asking many questions in a single question. You should liimit the question to a single question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Should I edit the question and separate  it to 3 questions individually?

Comment: Yes, separate three questions into three individual questions. Users can answer properly. I think related questions about second and third questions are already asked. Please search once before you post new questions. Focus this question question on first question only.